# Problems accessing API from the frontend docker container

Tags: c#, docker, api, asp.net-core-webapi

When I create the docker container for the frontend and 2 API, the connection between the frontend (in .net6) giver me this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:6000)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short token)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Show raw exception details
HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:6000)
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(string host, int port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation<T>.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
Frontend.Controllers.Controller.Details(string searchString) in Controller.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

DockerFile API 1

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/AaaAPI/AaaAPI.csproj", "Services/AaaAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/AaaAPI/AaaAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/AaaAPI"
RUN dotnet build "AaaAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AaaAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AaaAPI.dll"]
```

DockerFile API 2

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/BbbAPI/BbbAPI.csproj", "Services/BbbAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/BbbAPI/BbbAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/BbbAPI"
RUN dotnet build "BbbAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BbbAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BbbAPI.dll"]
```

DockerFile Frontend

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Frontend/CccFrontend/CccFrontend.csproj", "Frontend/BookMemoriesFrontend/"]
COPY ["Services/BbbAPI/BbbAPI.csproj", "Services/BbbAPI/"]
COPY ["Services/AaaAPI/AaaAPI.csproj", "Services/AaaAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Frontend/CccFrontend/CccFrontend.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Frontend/CccFrontend"
RUN dotnet build "CccFrontend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CccFrontend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CccFrontend.dll"]
```

These dockerfiles are autogenerated in Visual Studio 2022, I tried with docker compose too and the result is the same.

It's strange because I can access the API's with postman.
When i try to run in Visual Studio without docker it runs perfectly.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but are the URLs different when running in Docker vs. running in VS?

Comment: No, I force the port and is running from localhost.

Comment: Pls show your dockfile ?

Comment: I added in the first post

Comment: Change the port to 8001 in app1 and 8002 in app2, then test.

Comment: I changed It hapens the same, I can open the default page, but when i click on a page that depends of API gives me the same error.